# How to write perl program which has unix fmt function by using loop?

Tags: perl

letter must be loaded from text file

and while we execute the perl program

output will be like 60 width per line.

Is there any source?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can help you solve problems but we won't do your work for you, and you'll need to provide us with a clearer explanation of what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, put some effort into your questions. You are missing punctuation and proper capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reformat email-like text data, look at [Text::Autoformat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aAutoformat). It allows to specify target width and handful of other options.